# Angular-Meteor Fast Render

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

Is there a way to use Meteor Fast Render (https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/fast-render) with Angular-Meteor and Angular routes/state?

Comment: Did you find any way to use fast render with angular ui router?